# Is there any other way to avoid TIme Limit Exceeded or simplify the given code?

Tags: c

i did the below code:

```
int n, q, l, r;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
    int a[n], i, j, sum;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    while(q--)
    {
        sum=0;
        scanf("%d %d", &l, &r);
        for(j=l-1;j<=r-1;j++)
        {
            sum+=a[j];
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
```

here n is to take the size of the array and q is the number of test cases. l & r are respectively lower and upper index limit. the goal is to take l & r for each test cases and print the summations of array elements from a[l] to a[r]. is there any other way to simplify the code to avoid a Time Limit Exceeded failure?

Comment: BTW please don't write `j <= r - 1` use more readable, idiomatic, and robust `j < r`.

Comment: Do not use uncommon abbreviations like TLE without explaining them.

Comment: It is simple application of prefix sum, you can also use segment tree, but as the values of array does not seem to change, prefix sum will work the best, Follow the instructions given in the answer by @a Li.

Comment: Please, now thay you have clarified that TLE means Time Limit Exceeeded, explain what time limit you are exceeding.  What kind of limitations does your program have and what is indeed such a Time limit you have imposed to your program.

Comment: By the way, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your program snippet into  a full, complete program,  to be able to reproduce your errors without having first to edit (and probably correct) them.

Answer (score 2):

[Prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)

Instead of your relatively slow approach, which for M sum queries takes O(N * M) time complexity, you can try to precompute sums of all of the prefixes in a separate array, let's say `prefixSum`.

```
int prefixSum[n];
int currentSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    currentSum += arr[i]; // arr = initial array. 
    prefixSum[i] = currentSum;
}
```

With that, computing a range sum from `l` to `r` becomes simple. Let's assume we precomputed `prefixSum` for an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`:

```
index: 0  1  2   3   4  
       1  3  6  10  15
```

Computing the sum of range [`2`, `4`], will be equivalent of getting prefixSum[`4`] - prefixSum[`2` - 1], or Sum1 - Sum2:

```
index: 0   1   [2]   3   [4]  
       1   3    6   10   15
       ^   ^    ^    ^    ^           Sum1  
       ^   ^                          Sum2  ( - )
                ^    ^    ^           Result
```

With that in mind, we can code our `calculate_sum` function to do just that:

```
int calculate_sum(int l, int r) {
    if (!l)
        return prefixSum[r];
    return prefixSum[r] - prefixSum[l - 1];
}
```

Now, since `calcuate_sum` does nothing but array access operations (constant O(1) time), our eventual time complexity for M queries will be O(M). Alongside our precomputation earlier to calculate `prefixSum`, the overall complexity will be O(N + M).

Comment: can you please explain the logic behind using "if(!l) return prefixSum[r];" ? i didnt get that logic.

Comment: @SanzidaHossain If `l` was 0, we just need to return the entirety of `prefixSum[r]` (or Sum1) without subtracting anything.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use segment tree here. actually this one is a pretty straight forward segment tree problem.

`segment tree :` A Segment Tree is a data structure that allows answering range queries over an array effectively, while still being flexible enough to allow modifying the array. This includes finding the `sum of consecutive` array elements `a[l…r]`, or finding the `minimum element` in a such a range in `O(logn)` time. Between answering such queries the Segment Tree allows modifying the array by replacing one element, or even change the elements of a whole subsegment. so it will be best if you try to solve your problem with segment tree.

[segment tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/)

Comment: Defining or explaining what a segment tree is is an essential part of this answer, and all essential information should be directly in the answer, not provided only as external links. External links “rot” over time as they change or vanish.